# Generar csv con List

Tags: java

Quiero generar un csv a partir de un list de objetos, para ello lo he pasado a un String [] los datos, porque no me estaba dejando hacer el

```
`writer.writeAll` ni el  writer.writeNext

     List<Documento> list = new ArrayList();
     doc = new Documento();
     doc.setGnId("gn1111");
     doc.setIdExpSec(1111);
     doc.setState("03");
     doc.setTypeDoc("algo");
     doc.setUpdateDate("0001");
     list.add(doc);
     doc = new Documento();
     doc.setGnId("gn2222");
     doc.setIdExpSec(2222);
     doc.setState("03");
     doc.setTypeDoc("algo2");
     doc.setUpdateDate("0002");
     list.add(doc);

      File file = new File("C:\\Users\\emartinp\\Desktop\\miCompartida\\algo.csv"); 
      FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter(file); 

        // create CSVWriter object filewriter object as parameter 
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile); 

        List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
             data.add(new String[] { list.get(i).getGnId(), list.get(i).getIdExpSec().toString(), list.get(i).getTypeDoc()});
             writer.writeAll(data); 
        }
        // closing writer connection 
        writer.close(); 
        System.out.println("fin");
```

Ahora mismo los datos están "a pelo", pero saldrán de una bbdd, el caso es que al ver el algo.csv que ha generado sale ->

```
"gn1111","1111","algo""gn1111","1111","algo""gn2222","2222","algo2"
```

El problema es que ha sacado 3 objetos cuando sólo tengo 2.

Si intento usar el  writer.writeNext(data);  me dice que no, que lo cambie.

¿Existe alguna manera de meter directamente el `list` sin tener que pasarlo a String []? de no ser así, ¿ cómo soluciono el problema de los duplicados ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```
List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\emartinp\\Desktop\\miCompartida\\algo.csv");
FileOutputStream outputfile = new FileOutputStream(file); 
OutputStreamWriter algo = new OutputStreamWriter(outputfile);
PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputfile, "UTF-8"));

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
             String linea = list.get(i).getGnId()+","+list.get(i).getIdExpSec().toString()+","+list.get(i).getTypeDoc();
             w.print(linea);
             w.flush(); 
        }
w.close();
```

Comment: Perfecto,muchas gracias